# Complete callback in Observable.prototype.subscribe in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

The complete callback does not work as expected. Let me explain:

See this picture, note the `complete` callback in `subscribe` method.
This `complete` function is only called when the `observerOrNext` is called. When some error happens, the `complete` is not called. This is right? There are another method to get a callback that always  is called when the process finish?

[image]

Example:

**When success:**

```
this.getData(params)
    .subscribe(
        successData => {
            // this is called
        },
        error => {
            // this is not called. Ok!
        },
        () => { // when complete
            // this is called, ok!
        }
    );
```

**When error:**

```
this.getData(params)
    .subscribe(
        successData => {
            // this is not called, ok!
        },
        error => {
            // this is called. Ok! Yeah!
        },
        () => { // when complete
            // this is not called, why god??
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `.finally` function.

> Invokes a specified action after the source observable sequence terminates gracefully or exceptionally. There is an alias called finallyAction for browsers < IE9

Here's an example: [finally.md](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md).

Answer (score 8):

For `rxjs 6` use `pipe/finalize`:

```
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.getData(params)
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      // this is called on both success and error
    })
  )
  .subscribe(
    (successData) => {  },
    (err) => {  }
  );
```